# How to increase gaps between stencil columns

Tags: javascript, jointjs, rappid

```
  this.stencil = new joint.ui.Stencil({
    paper: this.paper,
    width: 240,
    height: 500,
    label: 'Components',
    layout: {
      columnWidth: 80,
      columns: 2,
      rowHeight: 130,
    },
  });
```

I'm using this code to create two column layout in stencil. Is there a way to add any padding or increase the gap between the two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done by setting `dx` and `dy` property for horizontal and vertical gap respectively in `layout` configuration -

```
this.stencil = new joint.ui.Stencil({
    paper: this.paper,
    width: 240,
    height: 500,
    label: 'Components',
    layout: {
      columnWidth: 80,
      columns: 2,
      rowHeight: 130,
      dy: 10,
      dx: 10,
      deep: true
    },
  });
```

You can vary the value of `dx` and `dy` to achieve the gap you would really want.

You can refer "layout" under ui.Stencil. Here is the link - https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v2.3/ui.html#ui.Stencil

And the explanation for layout configuration is available at - https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v2.3/layout.html#layout.GridLayout